# How can I capture an optional asterisk with my regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get sections from an API which is in markdown, so I'm using this:
`(?<=\*\*(Test)\*\*)(.*?)(?=\*\*end\*\*)`
https://regex101.com/r/r8aiVk/1
Result here should be `Test` and then `this is a test`, which it is. Awesome.

This works fine, however, some titles have an asterisk at the end, which is where I'm running into an issue. I loop through titles with the one regex, but I want to capture that one optional asterisk.

So with this example following, I want to be able to capture the asterisk along with the rest:
https://regex101.com/r/r8aiVk/2
The result here should be `Test*` `this is a test`.

I've tried various different ways, such as `(\*?)` and a few other variants, but I am unable to get this working.

Comment: How about `(Test\*?)` etc.

Comment: @phuzi tried it, it doesn't capture the asterisk still. https://regex101.com/r/r8aiVk/3

Comment: However, why use lookarounds? Use `\*\*(Test\*?)\*\*(.*?)\*\*end\*\*`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/PytWKl/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew They both worked. The workarounds was a case of me Googling and compiling examples to get something working. That has made it a lot more clearer, though. I'm not sure why I didn't think of it like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookbehind implementation in JavaScript tricked you: to match the lookbehind pattern, the regex iterator goes backwards, and tries to match its pattern that way. Since it is executed at each location (your lookbehind is the first atom in the regex), it checks the start of string, then `*`, then `**`, then `T`, etc. and once it matches `**Test**`, it calls it a day. So, the next `*` is consumed with `.*?`.

You can get what you need using a mere consuming pattern:

```
/\*\*(Test\*?)\*\*(.*?)\*\*end\*\*/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PytWKl/2).

This pattern will be processed normally, from left to right, matching

- `\*\*` - a `**` substring
- `(Test\*?)`  - capturing `Test` or `Test*` into Group 1
- `\*\*` - a `**` substring
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\*\*end\*\*` - `**end**` substring.